Casting ray for "focus-past-infinity"?
I recently added depth-of-field to my ray-tracer and the results look great.  The process I'm using is:

Cast view ray as normal
Calculate point d away along the view ray, where d is the focus-distance.
Randomly sample a point on the aperture, and create a secondary ray with an origin of that point on the aperture, and a direction from that new origin to the point calculated in step 2.  If d is infinity, simply keep the original ray direction.

This works great and makes intuitive sense.  However what I don't quite understand is how to compute a ray when d is greater than infinity.  Obviously, a focus-distance that is greater than infinity means that the rays are all diverging and NOTHING is in focus.  However, this is a physical possibility with cameras.
A lot of the use-cases of my renderer involve a camera focused at infinity for astronomical observations.  So being able to render imperfect focus, including diverging "past-infinity" settings seems like it'd be a great idea.
One idea I had (somewhat motivated by geometric optics) would be to treat negative focus distances as being "past infinity".  In which case the algorithm becomes:

Cast view ray as normal
Calculate point d away along the view ray, where d is the focus-distance (negative)
Randomly sample a point on the aperture, and create a secondary ray with an origin of that point on the aperture, and a direction from that new origin to the point calculated in step 2.  But now, since this new direction is pointing behind the camera, negate it.

This exhibits the right property I want: For negative values of d, the rays would diverge and nothing would be in focus.  And the closer d is to negative infinity, the less spread out the rays would be (closer to "focused at infinity").
I'm not sure if there is a rigorously way to define this, as obviously "focused beyond infinity" isn't a real concept.  I'm just trying to create a way to allow me to have rays that diverge in a physically realistic (and controllable) way, similar to what happens to when a camera lens is focused passed infinity.  Does this method seem plausible?
